# DRF bulk insert crashes on serializer.data: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have python 3.6 and my Django 2.2.28

I have two serializers and I use `list_serializer_class` for bulk inserts.
I use viewset and in my viewset

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='bulk')
    def bulk_create(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=items, many=True)
    .........
    self.perform_create(serializer)
```

The data is successfully inserted into the database but when I try to get the data from the serializer

```
headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

I get the error: too many values to unpack (expected 2) probably beucase it's trying to decode the data using the first serializer and not the `list_serializer_class`

These are my serializers:

```
    class ItemsSerializer(object, serializers.ListSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
        name = serializers.CharField(source='name',
                                            max_length=90)
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            pass
        def create(self, validated_data):
            items = [Item(**item) for item in validated_data]
            return Item.objects.bulk_create(items)

    class Meta:
        model = ItemModel
        fields = ('id', 'name')
  
    class ItemSerializer(object, serializers.ModelSerializer):
        name = serializers.CharField(source='name',
                                            max_length=90)
        class Meta:
            list_serializer_class = ItemsSerializer
            model = ItemModel
            fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Trackeback

```
2024-02-22 14:56:19 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
2024-02-22 14:56:19     response = get_response(request)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
2024-02-22 14:56:19     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
2024-02-22 14:56:19     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 67, in sentry_wrapped_callback
2024-02-22 14:56:19     return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
2024-02-22 14:56:19     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
2024-02-22 14:56:19     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/component_djangorestframework.py", line 28, in _nr_wrapper_APIView_dispatch_
2024-02-22 14:56:19     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
2024-02-22 14:56:19     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
2024-02-22 14:56:19     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
2024-02-22 14:56:19     raise exc
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
2024-02-22 14:56:19     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/project/cms/api/pages.py", line 176, in bulk_create
2024-02-22 14:56:19     print("serializer", serializer.data)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 768, in data
2024-02-22 14:56:19     ret = super().data
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 556, in data
2024-02-22 14:56:19     return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
2024-02-22 14:56:19   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/serializer_helpers.py", line 18, in __init__
2024-02-22 14:56:19     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
2024-02-22 14:56:19 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback...

Comment: I've updated my question with the trackeback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My class `ItemsSerializer` extends both `serializers.ListSerializer` and `serializers.ModelSerializer` which is ok but when we try to access the property `data` in viewset we need the property from `serializers.ModelSerializer` so I've created a new property in `ItemsSerializer` named `db_data` with the code from `serializers.ModelSerializer` and now it works.

```
@property
def db_data(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'initial_data') and not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
        msg = (
            'When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you '
            'must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the '
            'serialized `.data` representation.\n'
            'You should either call `.is_valid()` first, '
            'or access `.initial_data` instead.'
        )
        raise AssertionError(msg)

    if not hasattr(self, '_data'):
        if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
        elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
        else:
            self._data = self.get_initial()
    return self._data
```

And I'm returning

```
return Response(serializer.db_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```